# What database level permissions are needed for to Transfer a Procedure to another schema

Tags: sql-server

I have a user that needs to move a set of tables and procedures from one schema to another. He has db_datareader, db_datawriter, and db_ddladmin privileges. When he runs the below, he gets an error. When I add db_owner priviledge, he is able to execute the below with no error. If I do not want him (and his team) to have db_owner but still have the capability to transfer db objects to different schemas, how can I accomplish this?

```
ALTER SCHEMA newSchema TRANSFER oldSchema.objectMoving
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions

> To transfer a securable from another schema, the current user must have CONTROL permission on the securable (not schema) and ALTER
> permission on the target schema.
>
> If the securable has an EXECUTE AS OWNER specification on it and the
> owner is set to SCHEMA OWNER, the user must also have IMPERSONATE
> permission on the owner of the target schema.
>
> All permissions associated with the securable that is being
> transferred are dropped when it is moved.

CONTROL on the database, schema or individual tables should work.  There isn't much difference between CONTROL at the db level vs db_owner, so it might be better to temporarily grant db_owner and then remove it vs directly granting CONTROL permissions.

Auditing members of the db_owner role is a straight forward, simple process.  Sorting through custom permission grants is substantially less clear.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to go this route since the ddladmin permission didn't do the job. Thanks for the response. I saw the CONTROL permission in the same link you sent. Again, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

[The ALTER SCHEMA documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) covers the permissions necessary. I would expect db_ddladmin to be sufficient, but each of the permissions required is interrogatable using sys.fn_my_permissions().